# generator matrix coefficient in convolutional code

Tags: convolution

I cant determine a type of the following code:

```
G_1=1   // g_1=1
G_2=11  // g_2=x+1
```

Accorsing to description, it is convolutional code but I dont understand the type ( code rate)?

Answer (score 1):

It is a *systematic*  rate-$\frac 12$ convolutional with constraint length $2$.